# db:seed - How to change a value on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the following db:seed which is live on heroku:

```
["Admin", "Member"].each do |role_name|
  Role.find_or_create_by_name(role_name)
end
```

Admin is ID=1 and Member is ID = 2, which is important to the entire app.

I want to change Member to Teammember,

how do I do that? if I delete the old records and reseed then the ID's will be off?

Suggestions?

Comment: it's really bad to depend of a id

Comment: so I should use some type of column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
member = Role.find_by_name("Member")
member.name = "Teammember"
member.save!
```

PS: don't rely on ID in your code ( use Role.find_by_name )

Comment: thanks. but where do I do that? Where does that live, and how do I send that to heroku?